# pgRouting and Openlayers error when insert controls variable

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, pgrouting, html

I've got another problem here :(
I'm following the foss4g_w12 tutorial for building a pgRouting WebApp using openlayers, everything goes well until I added the following statement to my code:

```
controls = {
          start: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(start, SinglePoint),
          stop: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(stop, SinglePoint)
        }
```

the map suddenly showed up like this:
[image]

I already refresh the browser and it didn't change, after I delete the code it goes normal again.
here is my entire javascript code:

```
    var SinglePoint = OpenLayers.Class.create();
    SinglePoint.prototype = OpenLayers.Class.inherit(OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
createFeature: function(evt) {
    this.control.layer.removeFeatures(this.control.layer.features);
    OpenLayers.Handler.Point.prototype.createFeature.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    });

    var start_style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
        externalGraphic: "start.png",
        graphicWidth: 18,
        graphicHeight: 26,
        graphicYOffset: -26,
        graphicOpacity: 1
    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);

    var stop_style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
        externalGraphic: "stop.png",
        graphicWidth: 18,
        graphicHeight: 26,
        graphicYOffset: -26,
        graphicOpacity: 1
    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);

     var result_style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
         strokeWidth: 3,
         strokeColor: "#ff0000",
         fillOpacity: 0
     }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);

     var map, parser, start, stop, downtown, result, controls;
     function init() {
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    numZoomLevels: 18,
    // approximately match Google's zoom animation
    zoomDuration: 10
});

// create Google Mercator layers
var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Physical",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
);
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets", // the default
    {numZoomLevels: 20}
);
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Hybrid",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20}
);
var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
);

// create Bing layers

// API key for http://openlayers.org. Please get your own at
// http://bingmapsportal.com/ and use that instead.
var apiKey = "AqTGBsziZHIJYYxgivLBf0hVdrAk9mWO5cQcb8Yux8sW5M8c8opEC2lZqKR1ZZXf";

var veroad = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    key: apiKey,
    type: "Road",
    wrapDateLine: true
});
var veaer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    key: apiKey,
    type: "Aerial",
    wrapDateLine: true
});
var vehyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    key: apiKey,
    type: "AerialWithLabels",
    wrapDateLine: true
});

// create OSM layers
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

// layer WMS Lokal
var admin1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Administrasi Kota Tangerang Selatan",
            "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/wms",
            {layers: "rute:admin1", format: "image/png", transparent: true},
            {maxScale: 150}
        );
var jalan1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Jalan Kota Tangerang Selatan",
            "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/wms",
            {layers: "rute:jalan1", format: "image/png", transparent: true},
            {maxScale: 150}
        );
start = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Start point", {style: start_style});
stop = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("End point", {style: stop_style});
downtown = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Downtown data area", {style: result_style});
result = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Routing results", {style: result_style});

// create a vector layer for drawing
//var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Vectors");

map.addLayers([
    gphy, gmap, gsat, ghyb, veroad, veaer, vehyb, mapnik, admin1, jalan1, start, stop, downtown, result
]);
parser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector();
    downtown.addFeatures([feature]);
    controls = {
          start: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(start, SinglePoint),
          stop: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(stop, SinglePoint)
        }
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(11879804.55, -700076.0324),12);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
//map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(vector));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
//map.zoomToMaxExtent();

}
```

please help me, because my routing function can't started yet

regards

Comment: that seems to be a projection problem

Comment: am I have to change the projection of all layers into EPSG:900913?

Comment: the necessary ones, not sure if all your layers are in 900913, follow this example: `http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3-alloverlays.html`, first try to get your basemap layers working, then add your layers above.

Comment: still no luck, my layers did not showed up :(

Comment: post the error messages, are you using firebug? if not, install it and then check the Net tab. Since you're using geoserver, likely you need to put projection stuff there.

Comment: actually all my layers are using EPSG:4326, I'm using firebug checked for errors but the error windows is clean

Comment: can you make a live demo?

Comment: i'm afraid i can't Gery, because I'm working in my localhost :(

Comment: I understand that, well if you can make your whole code available I could make a live demo and easily debug your app and see what is going wrong, that may help you out.

Comment: but my data was stored on local geoserver, do you know a free service (web) that provide geoserver online? Because I need the WMS layer

Comment: no idea about that, I think you'd need to pay for it.

Comment: hi @Gery I tried my code again and got this error from firebug : TypeError: OpenLayers.Class.create is not a function
 

var SinglePoint = OpenLayers.Class.create();

Comment: hi @iqnaul, that means that the problem is there, comment that section and try agin, and check firebug.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `var SinglePoint = OpenLayers.Class.create();` is deprecated in OpenLayers 2.13 that I used. I added the deprecated.js script as one of the script source in my HTML head section. I thought it goes well now.